# Is this patent still in effect and inforced?

Tags: us5488743

In reference to the patent: [US5488743](https://www.google.com/patents/US5488743)

Good morning,

I hope all is well. I was looking through this patent and I see that the maintenance fees have lapsed. Does this mean the patent is not in effect  and in forced? Also, if my design differs from this design, what legal actions should I take so we do not interfer with this patent? Thank you for your help and I look forward to hearing from you soon.

Sincerely,

Joseph Lavinder
Lunos Inc.

Answer (score 1):

Lapsed patents are no longer enforceable.  You would need to take no legal actions unless you have invented an improvement on the lapsed patent that you wish to prosecute.

You would need to do your  own research and patent searches.

Not intended as legal advise please seek your own counsel.

If you like my answer please mark it as answered.